# Python selenium wait until not waiting to search appear

Tags: selenium, webdriverwait

I'm trying to wait until the search applies on optgroup, but it seems that the WebDriverWait.until method do nothing. 
this is how it looks on chrome inspect :

```
<select name="potentialrecipients[]" id="potentialrecipients" multiple="multiple" size="20" class="form-control no-overflow">
  <optgroup label="Potential badge recipients (1)">
    <option value="39676">Daniel (12345, daniel@blabla.com)</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

here is my code:

```
searchBox = driver.find_element_by_id('potentialrecipients_searchtext')
searchBox.send_keys('12345')

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='potentialrecipients']/optgroup[@label='Potential badge recipients (1)']/option"))

element.click()
```

this is the error I'm getting :

```
elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='potentialrecipients']/optgroup[@label='Potential badge recipients (1)']/option"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

when I'm trying to wait for the search to applies using debug, it's working perfectly.

What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//select[@id='potentialrecipients']//option[@value='39676']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Amazing, Worked!